# SMBShare Persmission on multiple Servers

Tags: powershell, security, active-directory, smb

i'm trying to create a script that checks for permissions of SmbShares on a few Servers.
The goal is to check if any share has a "everyone" permission. However i trying a find a more elegant solution than this mess:

```
$ADComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "Test-Server-*' | Where-Object { $excludeList -notcontains $_.name }

foreach ($server in $ADComputer) {
    $shares = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbShare }

    foreach ($share in $shares) {
        $permissions = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $share.name }
        
        foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
            if ( $permission ) ...
        }
    }
}
```

I can't wrapp my head around this. How can i solve this without using so many nested for loops?

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good pattern to follow here is:

- Solve the whole problem for local execution on a single machine
- Use `Invoke-Command` to repeat across multiple remote hosts

So let's start by writing a single function/script to solve the problem locally first:

```
function Find-SmbShareEveryoneGrant {
  # We can pipe the output from one cmdlet to the next, and solve the problem in a single pipeline
  Get-SmbShare |Get-SmbShareAccess |Where-Object { $_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow' -and $_.AccountName -eq 'Everyone'}
}
```

Now that you have a function that can be repeated anywhere, it's as simple as calling `Invoke-Command` against all the servers - the `-ComputerName` parameter accepts an array, so explicitly looping over `$ADComputers` is not necessary:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ADComputer -ScriptBlock ${function:Find-SmbShareEveryoneGrant} |Select PSComputerName,Name,ScopeName,AccessRight
```

4-5 lines of code total, much more concise than all those nested loops and successive calls to `Invoke-Command`

Comment: This is great. Cheers! I'm new to powershell so please forgive me for my stupidity. Never thought that the solution could be this simple. I didn't know that Invoke-Command can take an array as input, but i will edit my scripts :) 

Again: Thank you so much!